# How to say "He likes something" without using は?

Tags: particles

Typically, you would say 「彼は寿司が好きです。」 to say "He likes sushi." But assuming the "topic" of the sentence was something else and you couldn't use は without repeating it (if that's an option), what particles would you use?
…彼◯寿司◯好きです。

Edit: Should also clarify that I mean the subject is necessary. Removing 彼 or the person's name is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a pause, although this would be informal.

> - 彼、寿司好き.

Although, I don't see why you can't repeat using a は.

> - 食べ物は彼は寿司が好きです。

Why is this not an option for you?  Can you give examples or more context?

Comment: This is just something I thought of recently and didn't know what was appropriate. I was under the impression that you shouldn't use は more than once per clause, but if that's okay, then that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: The sentence 食べ物は彼は寿司が好きです sounds awkward or even incorrect to me.  I would say something like 食べ物では彼は寿司が好きです or 彼の好きな食べ物は寿司です, but in the former, it is arguable that the は in 食べ物では is not a topic marker but a contrastive particle, so I am not sure it answers the OP’s question.